# So I've got a school project to make a German grammar-help-tool using c#

Tags: c#

I recently started learning c# So I got a school assignment to make a German grammar-help-tool. It's a group assignment my task is:

The application loads prefabricated sentences from a file, and randomly makes small changes to these sentences. For example, commas can be deleted, `ies` can be replaced by `i`, `s` can be replaced by `ss`, and so on. The user is presented with the changed sentence, and it is up to him to find the error.

I tried using the string. Replace and streamReader/Writer, but it didn't work.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\kamil\OneDrive\Dokumente\test grammatik.txt"));
string fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
fileContent = fileContent.Replace("tier", "aff");

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("C:\test grammatik.txt"));
writer.Write(fileContent);
writer.Close();
```

the sentance in the txt file is: "Ein grosses Tier" and I wanted to replace the "Tier" with "Aff" and it's what i expected and I got:

> System.IO.IOException: 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'C:\Users\kamil\source\repos\test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ est grammatik.txt''

in the Line:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("C:\test grammatik.txt"));
```

[link to my file]https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0r3us5o0ik0oju/test.zip?dl=0

Comment: what error do you get, when it does not work? can you provide a primitive sample of your file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately "but it didn't work" is *never* enough information - what did you expect to see, what did you see?

Comment: the sentance in the txt file is: "Ein grosses Tier" and I wanted to replace the "Tier" with "Aff" and it's what i expected and I got:  System.IO.IOException: 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'C:\Users\kamil\source\repos\test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ est grammatik.txt''  and it was in the Line:  StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("C:\test grammatik.txt"));

Comment: Put any information in the question itself, not the comments. Post the actual, full exception text. At least in `File.OpenWrite("C:\test grammatik.txt")` the backslash isn't escaped so `\t` is treated as a tab. You should either escape it or use a verbatim string.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with this line

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("C:\test grammatik.txt"));
```

you need to either make `"C:\\test grammatik.txt"` or `@"C:\test grammatik.txt"`

I would not either suggest you write directly to c: root, you might end up getting permission issues, therefore make a temp folder to work on.

In addition as @Panagiotis Kanavos mentioned in a comment, a single backslash is treated as a tab, you can overcome this by a double backslash or adding @ symbol as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I tried doing this and now the output is this:Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\kamil\OneDrive\Desktop\Program.cs(9,11,9,18): error CS0101: The namespace 'test' already contains a definition for 'Program'
1>C:\Users\kamil\OneDrive\Desktop\Program.cs(11,21,11,25): error CS0111: Type 'Program' already defines a member called 'Main' with the same parameter types
1>Done building project "test.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: This is another question, you can not have 2 main methods in all programming languages, main should be only one place and it is the entry point for the program to start. that said as mentioned this is another question to what you have asked. I suggest you create a new question and share what you have to get a justified answer.

Answer (score -3):

The replace function asks for chars, not strings

```
public String Replace(char oldChar, char newChar);
```

in most languages strings are defined with " ", in the other hand chars use ' '

Good luck with your hw

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-7.0#system-string-replace(system-string-system-string)

Comment: [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-7.0) has 3 overloads with `string` and only one with `char`. The runtime error complains about the path anyway, not `Replace`.